# asp net trying to save single column but i keep getting this error - ASP NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

keep getting this error when i try to edit single column in ASP NET MVC 5

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'naam', table
```

this is my post code

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "id,email")] user user)
    {
        var username = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

And this is the model

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace LiemersApp.Models.EntityModels
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    public partial class profiel
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public profiel()
        {
            this.meldingens = new HashSet<meldingen>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Email:")]
        public string email { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<meldingen> meldingens { get; set; }
    }
}
```

so im wondering why it doesnt work as i just want to save changes to the Email column any ideas why this is happening cause i cant figure it out

Greetings

Comment: Error is clear, you need to insert value into name column.

Comment: The method you have shown is for class `user` but the model you have shown is for class `profiel`! Show the correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you don't change only name property in your model, you map all fields that came and bind in controller. If you don't bind some properties the are `null` like your field in error.

You can change controller like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "id,email")] user user)
{
    var username = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var userChange = db.profiels.Single(x => x.id == user.id);
        userChange.email = user.Email;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(user);
}
```